Radon-Nikodym Derivative for Discrete Measure
Let's find out that for a discrete measure $\tau$ the Radon-Nikodym derivative of a measure $u$ with respect to $\tau$.
Is the following answer correct?
Let $K = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ be a finite set. The measure $\tau$ is discrete and supported on $K$. For simplicity, assume $\tau$ is the uniform probability measure on $K$, i.e.,
$$
\tau(\{x_i\}) = \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{for each} \, x_i \in K.
$$
Let $u$ be another measure on $K$, which can also be written in terms of its values at the points in $K$:
$$
u = \sum_{i=1}^n u(\{x_i\}) \delta_{x_i},
$$
where $\delta_{x_i}$ is the Dirac measure concentrated at $x_i$, meaning $\delta_{x_i}(A) = 1$ if $x_i \in A$ and 0 otherwise.
We will now compute the derivative of $u$ for a discrete measure $\tau$.
To find the Radon-Nikodym derivative, we need to find $f(x_i) = \frac{du}{d\tau}(x_i)$ such that:
$$
u(A) = \int_A f \, d\tau = \sum_{x_i \in A} f(x_i) \cdot \tau(\{x_i\}).
$$
Since $\tau(\{x_i\}) = \frac{1}{n}$, we have:
$$
u(A) = \sum_{x_i \in A} f(x_i) \cdot \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Therefore, for this to match the expression for $u(A)$, we need:
$$
u(\{x_i\}) = f(x_i) \cdot \frac{1}{n},
$$
which gives:
$$
f(x_i) = u(\{x_i\}) \cdot n.
$$
Hence, the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $u$ with respect to $\tau$ at point $x_i$ is:
$$
\frac{du}{d\tau}(x_i) = u(\{x_i\}) \cdot n.
$$
This result generalizes to any discrete measure $\tau$ (not just the uniform measure).

Yes, in the discrete case,$$\frac{du}{d\tau}(x_i) = \frac{u({x_i})}{\tau({x_i})},$$ which in this case becomes your last formula.
